# Change Project Folder Path in Visual Studio Template

Tags: c#, templates, visual-studio-2013

I´m working in visual studio item template, but in my solution i have 6 projects and I want to include my item template all the projects. the item code project is this one:

```
<VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005" Type="Item">
  <TemplateData>
    <DefaultName>WebAPI.cs</DefaultName>
    <Name>WebAPI</Name>
    <Description>&lt;No description available&gt;</Description>
    <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
    <SortOrder>10</SortOrder>
    <Icon>__TemplateIcon.png</Icon>
  </TemplateData>
  <TemplateContent>
      <Folder Name="Base" TargetFolderName="Base">
        <Folder Name="Interface" TargetFolderName="Interface">
          <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="I$fileinputname$.cs">IPesquisarEstruturaSIIMN.cs</ProjectItem>
        </Folder>
        <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="$fileinputname$N.cs">PesquisarEstruturaSIIMN.cs</ProjectItem>
      </Folder>
 </TemplateContent>
</VSTemplate>
```

My Question is My problem is how can I change the project target of my item template?

Comment: [This MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/y3kkate1%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) documents how VS searches for custom templates.  You can practice with File + Export Template.

Comment: I have a option, to exported item and template.. and in both option i don´t have instructions to include item in other projects..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is there : [visual-studio-how-to-create-a-solution-template-with-multiple-projects](https://www.jayway.com/2015/03/13/visual-studio-how-to-create-a-solution-template-with-multiple-projects/)

It´s more eficienty to use projet template one by one.

```
    <VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005" Type="ProjectGroup">
  <TemplateData>
    <Name>CijunMVC</Name>
    <Description>Cria um projeto MVC no padrão Cijun MVC</Description>
    <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
    <ProjectSubType>
    </ProjectSubType>
    <SortOrder>1000</SortOrder>
    <CreateNewFolder>true</CreateNewFolder>
    <DefaultName>CijunMVC</DefaultName>
    <ProvideDefaultName>true</ProvideDefaultName>
    <LocationField>Enabled</LocationField>
    <EnableLocationBrowseButton>true</EnableLocationBrowseButton>
    <Icon>__TemplateIcon.png</Icon>
  </TemplateData>
    <TemplateContent>
    <ProjectCollection>
      <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="$projectname$_Entidade">
        Cijun_Entidade\entidade.vstemplate
      </ProjectTemplateLink>
      <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="$projectname$_Negocio">
        Cijun_Negocio\Negocio.vstemplate
      </ProjectTemplateLink>
      <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="$projectname$_Persistencia">
        Cijun_Persistencia\Persistencia.vstemplate
      </ProjectTemplateLink>
      <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="$projectname$_WebMVC">
        CijunWebMVC\Web.vstemplate
      </ProjectTemplateLink>
    </ProjectCollection>
  </TemplateContent>
</VSTemplate>
```

Answer (score 2):

The template definition applies for all of Visual Studio. 
In order for Visual Studio to find it, copy the .vstemplate, PesquisarEstruturaSIIMN.cs, IPesquisarEstruturaSIIMN.cs, and __TemplateIcon.png files to a new folder under the Item Templates folder. 
Ex: `C:\Users\MyUser\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Templates\ItemTemplates\MyTemplate`

Then restart Visual Studio, right click on each project, select "Add", then "New Item." You should see your template as an option under Visual C# Items.